# Issues with Loading Profile Avatars via YouTube API

Tags: get, youtube

I'm attempting to use the YouTube API to retrieve profile avatars of channels. In the API response, I'm obtaining avatar URLs in various sizes, such as `default`, `medium`, and `high`. However, when I try to load the image using these URLs, I encounter difficulties.

Here's an example:

```json
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/IWDgYfKTBzLrcaTNNOSJY2IIXySP756_g_RKyUjnV5XYd0KUMC0aRsz88J05nnbjXBi644YKIcw=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "width": 88,
            "height": 88
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/IWDgYfKTBzLrcaTNNOSJY2IIXySP756_g_RKyUjnV5XYd0KUMC0aRsz88J05nnbjXBi644YKIcw=s240-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "width": 240,
            "height": 240
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/IWDgYfKTBzLrcaTNNOSJY2IIXySP756_g_RKyUjnV5XYd0KUMC0aRsz88J05nnbjXBi644YKIcw=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
            "width": 800,
            "height": 800
          }
        },
```

The issue is that I'm receiving the same response for any query across different channels.

my request: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={API}&part=contentDetails,snippet,statistics,brandingSettings&id={channelid}`

I suspect that there might be additional steps or authorization required to gain access to these avatars. Could there be any particular considerations or requirements when using avatar URLs within the YouTube API?

Comment: *the same response for any query across different channels* they look identical but aren't identical, otherwise share such request URLs.

Comment: yes, each channel returns a slightly different response, but in all cases I don't get a valid image

Comment: What makes [the high resolution avatar](https://yt3.ggpht.com/IWDgYfKTBzLrcaTNNOSJY2IIXySP756_g_RKyUjnV5XYd0KUMC0aRsz88J05nnbjXBi644YKIcw=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj) ([WebArchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230820095040/https://yt3.ggpht.com/IWDgYfKTBzLrcaTNNOSJY2IIXySP756_g_RKyUjnV5XYd0KUMC0aRsz88J05nnbjXBi644YKIcw=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj)) as not being *valid*?

Comment: in this example: https://yt3.ggpht.com/IWDgYfKTBzLrcaTNNOSJY2IIXySP756_g_RKyUjnV5XYd0KUMC0aRsz88J05nnbjXBi644YKIcw=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj
I get an image, that can't be reached

Comment: As [the WebArchive snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20230820095040/https://yt3.ggpht.com/IWDgYfKTBzLrcaTNNOSJY2IIXySP756_g_RKyUjnV5XYd0KUMC0aRsz88J05nnbjXBi644YKIcw=s800-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj) shows that the image can be reached, you seem to have a network issue.